# Using jQuery / JavaScript to float element to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2ofknjq/)

Hello,

I found sticky sidebar jQuery script, but the fixed element (sidebar) floats to the left once I start scrolling down. I am trying to keep it on the right-hand side the whole time. Also, I am trying to get some spacing around sidebar once it starts scrolling, as now it's just stuck to the very top.

I trust it's a simple fix but JavaScript is like a dark forest to me, I tried to change couple things, tried to look online but can't seem to find the answers or I just don't know how to look for them so I apologise if this has been asked before.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "document ready!" );

  var $sticky = $('.sticky');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');
  if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickOffset = 0;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
      } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
      } else {
          $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left
}

.header {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 90px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.content {
  float: right;
  width: 640px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 800px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar sticky">
    This is side bar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is main content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="sticky-stopper"></div>
    This is my footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the **Sticky-Kit.js** plugin. That worked for me. See below, it keeps your sidebar to the right the entire time and has the **sticky** effect you're after:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("document ready!");

  $(".sidebar").stick_in_parent();

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left
}

.header {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 90px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 640px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 800px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 820px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/leafo/sticky-kit/v1.1.2/jquery.sticky-kit.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar sticky">
    This is side bar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is main content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="sticky-stopper"></div>
    This is my footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't stop at the footer? How to change that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to apply css on scroll to the element to achieve the desired effect.

Change the JavaScript as follows:

```
if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
    $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff, right: '0px' });
} else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
    $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset, right: '0px' , margin: '10px 10px 0px 0px'});
} else {
    $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial',  right: "0px", margin: '0px'});
}
```

A css property of `right:0px` is applied to the element on scroll, since it's position becomes `aboslute` on scroll.

`margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px` was also applied to the element to provide additional spacing around it when scrolling. This is then sent to `margin:0px` when the scroll stops.

You will also need to adjust the css of the `content` css class, if you do not want your side bar sitting on top of the content area.

```
.content {
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 800px;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k2ofknjq/2/) is an updated fiddle demonstrating these changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the sidebar moves using horizontal scrolling. Is it possible to make it move next to the content box, without moving horizontally?

Comment: @Oful , I'm not sure I follow what you mean by the side bar being moved next to the content box on horizontal scrolling. It is already next to the content box??